# Wire.h not found!

Tags: arduino-ide, library, wire-library, core-libraries

Here's the code that's making this error:

```
#include "Wire.h"
```

Here's the error:

```
fatal error: Wire.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Wire.h"
                  ^
compilation terminated.
Error compiling.
```

I also can't include any file from my `Arduino\libraries` folder. I tried to reinstall the IDE several times in different places and nothing happened. Why is this happening?

EDIT: after some time I discovered that this error occurs in header files only, not in sketches!

Comment: Could you clarify a little more on your setup of the IDE and the full paths to those libraries and if you have any duplicates. Also what is the settings you chose in the Boards menu.

Comment: D:\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\Wire\Wire.h And I chose the Arduino Uno COM3

Comment: Is the library there header there(I know its an obvious ques). That is where the arduino system should be looking when UNO is chosen

Comment: yes it is there

Comment: try hard linking it to the exacr path in the `#include` macro. Also what version of the IDE are you using?

Comment: my version is 1.6.3

Comment: Change it from `#include "Wire.h"` to `#include <Wire.h>`

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: Delete your IDE. Delete your preferences.txt file. Download and install 1.6.9

Answer (score 4):

Use `#include <Wire.h>`

Including files in double quotes (") will point to headers in current working directory first.

Edit: ... and there is nothing wrong with copying headers to CWD if you are modifying them, but that's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First go to your library folder and check whether u included that Wire.h header file or not.If not then first include that file then problem will get solved automatically.

Comment: The line that is causing the problem in the include statement, the one you think will fix it. If that's not what you mean please can you clarify your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found this question. However, the solution for me is different.

I already had `#include <Wire.h>`, nevertheless the compiler told me it's missing. It turned out, I had selected a wrong board from a previous project. Needed to change to "Arduino Uno".

Answer (score 0):

I copy here the answer from https://forum.arduino.cc/t/wire-h-no-such-file-or-directory-solved/297761, cause it worked for me:

> It's not enough to put "#include <Wire.h>" in the source file you are using the library in. It seems you must also put "#include <Wire.h>" in the main *.ino file for the sketch as well, before it can be used in any other source code files.